# Notification in android system tray, does not work

Tags: java, android, notifications

i have set up the code for receiving notifications but it is not working:

```
                String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
                int icon = R.drawable.messages_received;
                CharSequence contentTitle = "TITLE";
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

                Notification notification  = builder
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(icon)
                        .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                        .setContentText(message.getMessage())
                        .build();

                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

                final int NOTIFY = 1;
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY, notification);
```

I am using it on my MainActivity, and i tryied it as the telephone is in standby.
How can i solve? Does it need some other code?
I followed this guide: [http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/android/android-4.0/out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/android/android-4.0/out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Thanks

Comment: What's the OS version you're testing this on?

Comment: Android 10, but i would like a solution for older OS also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.test.services";
     public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "UploadBackgroundService";
     public static final int FOREGROUND_ID = 1339;
    
    private void createAndShowForegroundNotification() {
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    
                NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
                chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
                manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                assert manager != null;
                manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
    
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
                Notification notification = notificationBuilder
                        .setContentTitle("Image upload service")
                        .setContentText("Uploading Images...")
                        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logoo)
                        .setAutoCancel(false)
                        .build();
                manager.notify(FOREGROUND_ID, notification);
            } else {
                manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID )
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setContentTitle("Image upload service")
                        .setContentText("Uploading Images...")
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logoo)
                        .setAutoCancel(false);
                Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
                manager.notify(FOREGROUND_ID, notification);
            }
        }

try this code.replace the required parameters with your own.
```

Comment: Krishan Madushanka, what does startForeground stands for? it is missing some code..

Comment: i tryied your code but it doesn't work also, i see that if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { .... evaluates to true, but no notifications appear, why?

Comment: try setting `.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.logo))
  .setBadgeIconType(R.mipmap.logo)` as well

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code:

```
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "messages-id";
public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "messages";
public static final int FOREGROUND_ID = 1339;

private void notifyForeground(String message) {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentTitle("New message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.messages_received)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        manager.notify(FOREGROUND_ID, notification);
    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID )
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentTitle("New message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.messages_received)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        manager.notify(FOREGROUND_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

Thanks